# Export file using Sybase Event

Tags: sql, csv, events, export, sybase

I'm trying to output a file to a shared folder, I can make the output but I can't run it on a event/Stored Procedure.

The code snippet that I have to the output is this:

```
BEGIN 
    select * from table1; output to 'c:\\teste.txt' format text with COLUMN names
END
```

But when I include this in a event, the sybase gives me this error.

[Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'output' on line 2
SQLCODE: -131
SQLSTATE: 42000
SQL Statement: ALTER EVENT "dba"."Export" HANDLER BEGIN 
    select * from table1; output to 'c:\teste.txt' format text with  format text with COLUMN names
END

I am using Sybase Central with sql anywhere 12

Comment: Please include the error.

Comment: Also, please specify which Sybase database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unload table statment in Event.

"Output to..." will onsly work in DBISQL

Example:

```
UNLOAD SELECT field1, field2 from table1 to 'c:\temptest.csv QUOTES OFF DELIMITED BY ';';
```